# How to increase 'numpy.ndarray' matrix

Tags: numpy

input array:

```
   import numpy as np

   a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
   '''
   >>> a
   array([[1, 2],
         [3, 4]])
```

Output should be:

```
   >>>
   array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

   '''
```

How to get output like this?

Comment: Look into `np.pad`.

Comment: Please spend some minutes to get familiar with the formatting options (code & text) and use them appropriately. Plus, the question has nothing to do with machine learning (tag removed)

Comment: How to do padding for RGB images..?
It will be in (28,28,3)

And need to save it in (32,32,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.pad` can be used for this, see the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.lib.pad(a, pad_width=((2,2),(2,2)), mode='constant')
```

Comment: How to do padding for RGB images..? 

If it will be in (28,28,3) And need to save it in (32,32,3)